# Define scope inside directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("validation", validation);

function validation() {

  var validation = {
    controller: controller,
    link: link,
    replace: false,      
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
      phrase: ""
    }
  };

  return validation;

  function controller(scope) {
    scope.phrase = "hello";
  } 

  function link(scope, element, attributes) { } 

}
```

When I apply it I get the error "Invalid isolate scope definition for directive".

I am defining a scope as I need child directives to access scope.phrase.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should specify which type of isolate scope the variable should be:

try:

```
scope: {
  phrase: "="
}
```

I recommend having a read here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives

Comment: Then I get Unknown provider: scopeProvider <- scope because I have controller(scope). What I need is to set scope.errors = attributes.errors. How can I do this?

Comment: scope is not a Angular service, You probably mean `$scope` and you need to inject it before usage.

Comment: Have a read here about how to inject services to your components: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: But can I inject $scope in directive link?

Comment: Thats not necessary as the the first argument passed to the linking function is scope. But you can inject it into the controller function you are using.

Comment: Try putting the line you have in the controller function into your link function! Then you dont need to inject scope into the controller.